# Retrieving PDF stored in blob field please

Tags: php, mysql

please can any one help with a PHP/Mysql script that can enable the download of PDF stored in a blob when a link 'DOWNLOAD NOW' is clicked. i have tried but no result. kindly help Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = ... // data retrieved from BLOB field
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="THE_NAME_OF_THE_FILE_TO_BE_DOWNLOADED.pdf"');
echo $pdf;
```

Comment: Consider adding a `Content-Length` header - especially if the files are "big".